# Finding the sum of the real parts squared of the roots of unity

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I was solving a diophantine equation when I reached this point and I got stuck finding the value of
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n  \cos^2\left(\frac{360^{\circ}}n k\right).$$
I noticed that this sum resembles the sum of the real parts squared of the roots of unity.
After graphing the function and/or plugging in some values you can quickly realize that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n  \cos^2\left(\frac{360^{\circ}}n k\right) = \frac n2$$
for all natural numbers greater than $2.$

- How can we prove this?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\cos^2(2\pi k/n)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n(\cos(4\pi k/n)+1)=\frac{n}{2}$$ since $\sum_{k=1}^n\cos(4\pi k/n)=\mathrm{Re}\sum_{k=1}^ne^{4\pi ki/n}=0$.

Comment: why is this true $ \mathrm{Re}\sum_{k=1}^ne^{4\pi ki/n}=0$

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{4\pi ik/n}=1+\omega+\cdots+\omega^{n-1}=\frac{1-\omega^n}{1-\omega}=0$ since $\omega^n=e^{4\pi i n/n}=1$.